# How can I change my plot that it doesn't look that filled?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to have a not that filled plot.

[image]

that is my code

```
ggplot(master, aes(x = Income, y = BMI, group = BMI, color = weight_class)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point()+labs(title = "Correaltion between Income and BMI")+ scale_y_log10()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "not that filled"?  Here are a few options:

You could change the alpha parameter to make the points more transparent with something like `alpha=.25`.

```
ggplot(master, aes(x = Income, y = BMI, group = BMI, color = weight_class)) + 
  geom_line(alpha=.25) + 
  geom_point(alpha=.25)+
  labs(title = "Correaltion between Income and BMI")+ 
  scale_y_log10()
```

You could change the plotting symbols to open rather than filled in circles with `shape=1`.

```
ggplot(master, aes(x = Income, y = BMI, group = BMI, color = weight_class)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  labs(title = "Correaltion between Income and BMI")+ 
  scale_y_log10()
```

You could also randomly sample a fraction of the observations in each group - the code below samples 10% from each group:

```
master %>% 
group_by(weight_class) %>%
sample_frac(.1) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Income, y = BMI, group = BMI, color = weight_class)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()+
  labs(title = "Correaltion between Income and BMI")+ 
  scale_y_log10()
```